# ipad lockdown: launch app on boot?

Tags: iphone, security, ipad, ios4

We have a need for warehouse staff to use an ipad app for stock control.

Is it possible to lock down the ipad and only show/launch our custom app on screen.  So i want to remove/hide/disable all other apps except ours.

Cheers,
Trav.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not certainly not possible without jailbreaking the device.

Comment: I agree, if you have one purpose for it why is it not jailbroken.

Comment: can you explain how i would do this if jailbroken?

Comment: I advise you not to jailbreak a phone for use in a commercial environment, especially if you haven't got a technical support person in your company with good knowledge of iPad/Apple to support it.  Maybe I'm just being paranoid, but security would be my main concern.

Answer (score 4):

Almost.

You can use Apple's official [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/) to lock down most features of the iPad so that only your app can be installed, render many of the built-in apps useless, and prevent (re)configuring wifi, email, etc.  But the user will still be shown a whole bunch of other stuff they can't use. You can move all the apps other than your own to the second page.  An enterprise account is not required to run this utility.

A firewall in conjunction a VPN that all the iPads are configured locked to might also be helpful.

ADDED:

There is also a trick to hide all the other icons on stock OS devices, but it requires a fair amount of [work](http://macenstein.com/default/2008/09/how-to-delete-apples-apps-from-your-iphone-aka-the-hidden-10th-iphone-app-screen/).

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know it's not possible to boot in a specific app, but it is possible to 'lock' the iPad in one app using Guided Access:

http://www.imore.com/how-restrict-access-specific-app-guided-access-iphone-and-ipad

Note that this even works with a website, provided you have made a 'web app' using [these meta tags](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW2).

Answer (score 0):

not really, but if you set the iPad up with parental controls you can probably lock it down to some degree.

Answer (score -1):

Look into Guided Access which will allow you to lock it on one app and act like a kiosk.

Comment: A link to Apple's section in the documentation regarding this topic might be usefull